# How to filter by attributes of attributes of an Entity class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'm using Hibernate in Java to map classes to DB tables. I have a Person table, each entry has many Pets, each of which has many Toys.

I'd like to be able to filter these in my DAO based on attributes of the toys; for example, find all people with pets that have red toys, as a `List<Person>`. How can I filter on this?

Person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Pet> pets;

    ...
}
```

Pet class:

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pet")
    private List<Toy> toys;

    ...
}
```

Toy class:

```
@Entity
public class Toy {

    ...
    private String colour;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean 'filter' in this case, but you can always use HQL.
For example:

```
select p from Person p 
              inner join p.pets as pets
              inner join pets.toys as toys
              where p.pets.size() > 0 
              and toys.color = 'red'
```

Maybe where condition '**p.pets.size() > 0**' is redunant here, because of inner join.

Comment: No luck there - it returns all colours of toys.

Comment: select person0_.personId as personId1_18_ from Person person0_ 
inner join PET pets1_ on person0_.personId=pets1_.PERSONID 
inner join TOY toys2_ on toys1_.id=toys2_.PETID 
where toys2_.colour=?